# Magnolia: How to enable I18N in a multivalue composite field?

Tags: internationalization, magnolia

**How to enable I18N in a multivalue composite field in Magnolia 5.4.1?** In my yaml, I have set `i18n: true` in every section, however, in the dialog I can only provide one value for the fields for all languages, they don't have I18N support.

The relevant fields are the "`features`", which each holds a title and an image.

My .yaml:

```
actions:
  cancel:
    class: info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.CancelDialogActionDefinition
  commit:
    class: info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.SaveDialogActionDefinition

form:
  label: Abschnitt
  tabs:
    - name: tabMain
      label: Abschnitt
      fields:
        - name: image
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.LinkFieldDefinition
          targetWorkspace: dam
          appName: assets
          identifierToPathConverter:
            class: info.magnolia.dam.app.assets.field.translator.AssetCompositeIdKeyTranslator
          contentPreviewDefinition:
            contentPreviewClass: info.magnolia.dam.app.ui.field.DamFilePreviewComponent
          label: Bild
          required: false
          i18n: true
        - name: bodyText
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.RichTextFieldDefinition
          configJsFile: /.resources/sorba-templates/webresources/ckeditor/config-magnolia.js
          rows: 6
          label: Text
          required: true
          source: true
          i18n: true
        - name: features
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.MultiValueFieldDefinition
          label: Features
          i18n: true
          transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.multi.MultiValueSubChildrenNodePropertiesTransformer
          field:
            name: compositeField
            class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.CompositeFieldDefinition
            transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.composite.NoOpCompositeTransformer
            layout: vertical
            i18n: true            
            fields:
              - name: title
                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
                label: Titel
                i18n: true
                required: true
              - name: image
                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.LinkFieldDefinition
                targetWorkspace: dam
                appName: assets
                identifierToPathConverter:
                  class: info.magnolia.dam.app.assets.field.translator.AssetCompositeIdKeyTranslator
                contentPreviewDefinition:
                  contentPreviewClass: info.magnolia.dam.app.ui.field.DamFilePreviewComponent
                label: Bild
                required: true
                i18n: true
```

The dialog only supports I18N for all other fields except for the "`features`" and the fields of such (title, image):

[image]

Comment: Issue reported: https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-6396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug report has been acknowledged by Magnolia: https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-6396. Should be fixed in a future version.

**Update:**

The bug report has been rejected, because it is actually possible already, just need to use a different transformer. See the comment here:

https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLUI-3610?focusedCommentId=114823&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-114823